# CSS Less mixins for keyframes

Tags: css

how to write Less mixin for keyframes.
I have tried in the following way but it is giving error, 
***ParseError: Directive options not recognized.***

```
.keyFrameAlert(@-webkit-keyframes);
```

### Mixin

```
.keyFrameAlert(@keyFrame){
    @keyFrame alert {
        0% { 
            opacity: 0; 
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 1; 
        }
        100% { 
            top: 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

can anybody help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be throwing an error because of the `@` prefix for your keyframes, so where your passing `@-webkit-keyframes` it thinks your trying to pass it a variable with that same name.

There is a slightly different approach to this, where you can declare your keyframes, and add a class inside it which contains your keyframe set.

```
@-webkit-keyframes alert {.keyframes;}
@keyframes alert {.keyframes;}

.keyframes () {
    0% { 
        opacity: 0; 
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    100% { 
        top: 0; 
    }
}
```

This is slightly different to what you were trying previously, as you would still need to type out all of your vendor prefixes, but you only need to change your keyframes in one place.

Comment: what if you want to change that opacity given different circumstances... ? how would you do a real mixin here?