# Mixin in Keyframe - possible?

Tags: animation, less, keyframe, less-mixins, lesshat

The following example is using the LESS HAT Mixin Lib 3.0.2:

```
.a {
    color: blue;
}
.b {
    color: green;
}
.keyframes(~'myanimation,0%{ .a() } 100%{ .b() }');
```

I'm not quite sure if the answer here is the best possible solution:
[CSS Less mixins for keyframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132116/css-less-mixins-for-keyframes)

I'm looking for a way to have several mixins fit in `keyframes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write normal Less code:

```
.a {
    color: blue;
}
.b {
    color: green;
}

@keyframes myanimation {
    0% {.a} 100% {.b}
}
```

And for vendor prefixing use Autoprefixer ([1](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer), [2](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix) or whatever [else](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#usage) suitable AP wrapper for your build enviroment). Nowadays there's absolutely no need for that ancient LessHat JavaScript hackery or explicitly hardcoded prefixes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was blind in a way. I'll take a better look at prefixers.